# Get End Date With Start Date Only Weekdays

Tags: php, date, datetime

I want to find an end date of my first date.

For example my first date is

```
2020-01-01 04:20:18
```

And I want to get 20 days after this first date but only the weekdays (exclude the saturday and sunday)

I created this

```
$expirationDate = date_format(date_add(date_create(date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($_POST['created_at']))),date_interval_create_from_date_string("20 day")),'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

The result I got is

```
2020-01-21 04:20:18
```

The end date result should be

```
2020-01-28 04:20:18
```

Because date 4,5,11,12,18,19,25,26 is saturday and sunday.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop and check which day of the week it is to achieve this. I've left your original `$expirationDate` calculation in to show the difference in the output:

```
$dt = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('2020-01-01 04:20:18'));
$expirationDate = date_format(date_add(date_create($dt),date_interval_create_from_date_string("20 day")),'Y-m-d H:i:s');

// Add 20 days
for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
    $dt = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($dt)));

    // Is it a Sunday or Saturday?
    $day = date('w', strtotime($dt));
    if ($day == 0 || $day == 6)
        // Deduct one from loop counter
        $i--;
}

// Output
echo $dt;
echo $expirationDate;
```

Output:

```
$dt =             2020-01-29 04:20:18 (correct)
$expirationDate = 2020-01-21 04:20:18 (incorrect)
```

**How does it work?**

It's quite straight-forward:

- Store the start date in `$dt`
- Loop from 0 to 19 (for 20 days)
- Add one day to `$dt`
- If the day is a Sunday (0) or a Saturday (6), subtract 1 from the loop counter (`$i`)

**An Alternative Solution**

As an alternative, this may be greatly simplified by simply adding four weeks to the start time:

```
$dt = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('2020-01-01 04:20:18'));
$dt = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+4 week", strtotime($dt)));
echo $dt;
```

However, this could only work if that start date was guaranteed to be a weekday.  Otherwise you'd end up with an end date on a weekend.

Comment: Can it work with hours too? example +1 hour?

Comment: Yes indeed it can